# can't access sub-subdomain: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I can't access to sub-subdomains.

For example `http://electricien.synerciel.fr` is working.

But, for sub-subdomains `http://electricite-lemonnier.electricien.synerciel.fr/` returns **`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`**

Here's the DNS configuration :

[image]

I don't know what's going on. I can't find any valid resource to explain what the error message means.

Comment: You are probably better off contacting Namebay's tech support. It looks to me like you have done everything correctly but maybe their interface has a different way of creating second-level subdomains or maybe there's a bug in their system that doesn't allow this. They should know the answers. It's their job.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem? I have the same problem!

Comment: It was on the hoster side (or dns hoster side)

Comment: It would have been nice if you provided an answer briefly describing what the hoster changed to the config to get it working.